# Sqlite database connectivity in html5 and angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, sqlite

Is there any way to store data into sqlite database with html 5 and angularjs for later upload?

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) into an Angular service as a persistence layer. Lawnchair is just a simple JSON persistence using your browser's local storage mechanisms. It has pretty good browser support considering.